# Creating an object's movement based on velocity in processing.js

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I am trying to draw birds whose wings oscillate based on their velocity. Simply put, the faster my birds fly, the faster their wings should oscillate.

My complete code is below and it doesn't do what I want. What I've done to create the oscillation is make `flyingFactor` vary based on the magnitude of `velocity` in my `displayAndMoveWings` function. However when I `draw` everything I find that, because `velocity` changes all the time (i.e. triggered by the random `acceleration` force in the `draw` function), so does `flyingFactor` and means that my birds' wings don't oscillate at all and look very buggy.

Any way to make it work? I want my birds' wings to look like they naturally oscillate, only faster and slower as my birds accelerate or decelerate.

Thank you so much in advance!

```
angleMode = "degrees";

var Bird = function(m,x,y){
    this.mass = m;
    this.position = new PVector(x,y);
    this.velocity = new PVector(0,0);
    this.acceleration = new PVector(0,0);
};

Bird.prototype.applyForce = function(force) {
    var f = PVector.div(force, this.mass);
    this.acceleration.add(f);
};

Bird.prototype.update = function() {
    this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
    this.position.add(this.velocity);
    this.acceleration.mult(0);
    this.velocity.limit(3);
};

Bird.prototype.displayAndMoveWings = function() {
    this.start=-110;
    this.stop = this.start + 110;
    this.flyingFactor=cos(360+frameCount*this.velocity.mag()*10)*20;
    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    strokeWeight(2);
    noFill();
    arc(this.position.x,this.position.y,this.mass,this.mass,this.start-this.flyingFactor,this.stop-this.flyingFactor);
    arc(this.position.x+this.mass,this.position.y,this.mass,this.mass,this.start+this.flyingFactor-70,this.stop+this.flyingFactor-70);  
};

Bird.prototype.checkEdges = function() {

  if (this.position.x > width) {
    this.position.x = 0;
  } else if (this.position.x < 0) {
    this.position.x = width;
  }

  if (this.position.y > height) {
    this.position.y = 0;
  } else if (this.position.y < 0) {
    this.position.y = height;
  }
};

var bird1 = new Bird(15, width/2, height/2);

var draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    bird1.update();
    bird1.displayAndMoveWings();
    var randomAcceleration = new PVector(random(-3,3),random(-3,3));
    bird1.checkEdges();
    bird1.applyForce(randomAcceleration);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a hack... Before my `displayAndMoveWings` function I created a new global variable called `whatIsVelocity`. Then in `displayAndMoveWings` I wrote the following:

```
if (frameCount % 60 === 0){
    whatIsVelocity = this.velocity.mag();
}
this.flyingFactor=cos(360+frameCount*whatIsVelocity*10)*20;
```

Effectively what this does is pull the velocity every 60 frames (approximately 2 seconds) and introduces that velocity into `flyingFactor`, meaning that it doesn't get recalculated every frame like in my previous code above. Not super pretty but it achieves my purpose.